# php artisan list - PHP Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'HEADER_FORWARDED'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Running `php artisan list` on my Laravel app is giving me an odd error. E.g.

```
php artisan list
PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'HEADER_FORWARDED' in /path/to/app/vendor/fideloper/proxy/config/trustedproxy.php on line 56
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Maybe comment out that packages service provider while getting the list. It seems like it's not expecting to work under CLI.

Comment: @aynber v4 (a legacy app). Note: `php artisan --version` gives me the same error message.

Comment: @apokryfos I get the same message when trying to run the app via a web server.

Comment: `HEADER_FORWARDED` appears to have been added in symfony's HttpFoundation in v2.7. Make sure you're updated to that version.

Comment: In that case, make sure you're using v2 of TrustedProxy. `You can still use this for Version 4 of Laravel. See the latest v2 tag of this repository, which is compatible with version 4 of Laravel.`